# Test conditional imports in unittest

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm trying to make a module compatible with both Python 2 and Python 3

I found this solution (https://github.com/IDSIA/sacred/issues/459#issuecomment-492627249) which makes `FileExistsError` available in Python 2

```
if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    import errno

    class FileExistsError(OSError):
        def __init__(self, msg):
            super(FileExistsError, self).__init__(errno.EEXIST, msg)
```

Is there a way to test this solution running a unit test in Python3 ?

Comment: If you're trying to write code that works in both Python 2 and 3, you should be running the tests in both 2 and 3 too (using e.g. tox), which would ensure this gets covered.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. this makes perfect sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work. The test will fail in Python 2 if you remove the class definition.

**code.py:**

```py
import errno, sys

if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    class FileExistsError(OSError):
        def __init__(self, msg):
            super(FileExistsError, self).__init__(errno.EEXIST, msg)
```

**test.py:**

```
import unittest, code

class test_FileExistsError(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        # built-in in Python 3
        ok1 = 'FileExistsError' in vars(code)['__builtins__']

        # self-defined in Python 2
        ok2 = 'FileExistsError' in vars(code)

        assert ok1 or ok2

unittest.main()
```